# How to implement clustering for Windows XP SP3 PCs

Tags: windows-xp, apache-2.2, cluster

In a nutshell, how should this be implemented? Basically, I want to cluster a file and web server running apache2.

Comment: How about a more detailed set of requirements? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't cluster workstations.

Comment: Why are you running apache on windows?

Comment: @Matt Rogish: I'm just doing an experiment. I've been running it under Linux for quite some time now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attempting to cluster machines running XP is a bad idea, it's not designed for it and will need some third party software to do so, if its even possible.

Your best bet is to invest in Server 2003 or 2008 (Enterprise Editions), that will support clustering, or alternatively look at a Linux solution.

Comment: 100 % agree with sir.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could spend upwards of $20,000 (US) for load balancing hardware to scale out your $100 OS, or you could buy Windows Server 2003/2008 standard at about $175 (US) each and run the free Netwok Load Balancing within Windows Server.

XP as an OS is not particularly suited for high volumne web sites.

Answer (score 1):

you could do *poorman's* round-robin DNS load balancing with them?
basically 2 a records with the same hostname for each box.

Write a script on each box to check if the other box is up.  & if its down, remove it's a record from dns.

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/rr.html

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Thanks.

Comment: Does the link help? You should also try to elaborate more :)

Answer (score 0):

Win XP is Desktop os and sure no one has try this out, other thing why you want to install apache 2 on win on there are so many open source os there to handed. Your Hardware is not matter for clustering suite if you have 128mb ram you can deploy clustering on that!

my suggestion to your case you can use centos old versions with cluster suite.

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2009/11/clustering-linux-ha.html